# How to add a UIView to a CALayer

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

I'm trying to add a custom `UIView` to a `CALayer` but it's not being rendered.

I'm not adding the custom view to another view. Instead I'm trying to add it directly to a `CALayer`.

If I do add the custom view to another view (i.e. `[self.view addSubview:customView]`), it works but for some reason starts causing crashes the minute the screen is touched.

So Basically

```
[self.view addSubview:customView];
[layer addSublayer:customView.layer]; //Causes crashes the minute the screen is touched
```

Below is the code:

```
CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

//I'm not adding the custom view to another view
//Instead I'm trying to add it to a CALayer

CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
[Layer setFrame:frame2];
[layer addSublayer: customView.layer];
```

P.S. My current workaround is to convert the UIView to a UIImage and add it to the CALayer.

Belo is the custom UIView Code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:ARCVIEW_DEFAULT_FONT_NAME size:ARCVIEW_DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE];
    self.text = @"Curva Style Label";

    NSLog(@"FONT = %@, TEXT = %@", self.font, self.text);

    self.radius = ARCVIEW_DEFAULT_RADIUS;
    self.showsGlyphBounds = NO;
    self.showsLineMetrics = NO;
    self.dimsSubstitutedGlyphs = NO;
    self.color = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.arcSize = ARCVIEW_DEFAULT_ARC_SIZE;
    self.shiftH = self.shiftV = 0.0f;
}
return self;
```

}

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame font:(UIFont *)font text:(NSString *)text radius:(float)radius arcSize:(float)arcSize color:(UIColor *)color{

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    self.font = font;
    self.text = text;
    self.radius = radius;
    self.showsGlyphBounds = NO;// Border add for each Text
    self.showsLineMetrics = NO;
    self.dimsSubstitutedGlyphs = NO;
    self.color = color;
    self.arcSize = arcSize;
    self.shiftH = self.shiftV = 0.0f;
}
return self;
```

}

```
typedef struct GlyphArcInfo {
CGFloat         width;
CGFloat         angle;  // in radians
```

} GlyphArcInfo;

```
static void PrepareGlyphArcInfo(CTLineRef line, CFIndex glyphCount, GlyphArcInfo *glyphArcInfo, CGFloat arcSizeRad)
```

{
    NSArray *runArray = (NSArray *)CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);

```
    // Examine each run in the line, updating glyphOffset to track how far along the run is in terms of glyphCount.
CFIndex glyphOffset = 0;
for (id run in runArray) {
    CFIndex runGlyphCount = CTRunGetGlyphCount((CTRunRef)run);

        // Ask for the width of each glyph in turn.
    CFIndex runGlyphIndex = 0;
    for (; runGlyphIndex < runGlyphCount; runGlyphIndex++) {
        glyphArcInfo[runGlyphIndex + glyphOffset].width = CTRunGetTypographicBounds((CTRunRef)run, CFRangeMake(runGlyphIndex, 1), NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }

    glyphOffset += runGlyphCount;
}

double lineLength = CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, NULL, NULL, NULL);

CGFloat prevHalfWidth = glyphArcInfo[0].width / 2.0;
glyphArcInfo[0].angle = (prevHalfWidth / lineLength) * arcSizeRad;

    // Divide the arc into slices such that each one covers the distance from one glyph's center to the next.
CFIndex lineGlyphIndex = 1;
for (; lineGlyphIndex < glyphCount; lineGlyphIndex++) {
    CGFloat halfWidth = glyphArcInfo[lineGlyphIndex].width / 2.0;
    CGFloat prevCenterToCenter = prevHalfWidth + halfWidth;

    glyphArcInfo[lineGlyphIndex].angle = (prevCenterToCenter / lineLength) * arcSizeRad;

    prevHalfWidth = halfWidth;
}
```

}

```
-(void)setText:(NSString *)text{
//[_string release];
_string = text;

[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

}

```
-(void)setArcSize:(CGFloat)degrees{

_arcSize = degrees * M_PI/180.0;
```

}

```
-(CGFloat)arcSize{
NSLog(@"arcSize %f",_arcSize * 180.0/M_PI);

return _arcSize * 180.0/M_PI;
```

}

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Don't draw if we don't have a font or string

NSLog(@"FONT = %@, TEXT = %@", self.font, self.text);

if (self.font == NULL || self.text == NULL) 
    return;

    // Initialize the text matrix to a known value
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //Reset the transformation
    //Doing this means you have to reset the contentScaleFactor to 1.0
CGAffineTransform t0 = CGContextGetCTM(context);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(self.xOffsetShadow, self.yOffsetShadow), self.blurShadow, self.shadowColor.CGColor);

CGFloat xScaleFactor = t0.a > 0 ? t0.a : -t0.a;
CGFloat yScaleFactor = t0.d > 0 ? t0.d : -t0.d;
t0 = CGAffineTransformInvert(t0);
if (xScaleFactor != 1.0 || yScaleFactor != 1.0)
    t0 = CGAffineTransformScale(t0, xScaleFactor, yScaleFactor);

CGContextConcatCTM(context, t0);

CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

if(ARCVIEW_DEBUG_MODE){
        // Draw a black background (debug)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.layer.bounds);
}

NSAttributedString *attStr = self.attributedString;
CFAttributedStringRef asr = (__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)attStr;
CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(asr);
assert(line != NULL);

CFIndex glyphCount = CTLineGetGlyphCount(line);
if (glyphCount == 0) {
    CFRelease(line);
    return;
}

GlyphArcInfo *  glyphArcInfo = (GlyphArcInfo*)calloc(glyphCount, sizeof(GlyphArcInfo));
PrepareGlyphArcInfo(line, glyphCount, glyphArcInfo, _arcSize);

    // Move the origin from the lower left of the view nearer to its center.
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMidX(rect)+_shiftH, CGRectGetMidY(rect)+_shiftV);

if(ARCVIEW_DEBUG_MODE){
        // Stroke the arc in red for verification.
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddArc(context, 0.0, 0.0, self.radius, M_PI_2+_arcSize/2.0, M_PI_2-_arcSize/2.0, 1);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

    // Rotate the context 90 degrees counterclockwise (per 180 degrees)
CGContextRotateCTM(context, _arcSize/2.0);

    // Now for the actual drawing. The angle offset for each glyph relative to the previous glyph has already been calculated; with that information in hand, draw those glyphs overstruck and centered over one another, making sure to rotate the context after each glyph so the glyphs are spread along a semicircular path.

CGPoint textPosition = CGPointMake(0.0, self.radius);
CGContextSetTextPosition(context, textPosition.x, textPosition.y);

CFArrayRef runArray = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);
CFIndex runCount = CFArrayGetCount(runArray);

CFIndex glyphOffset = 0;
CFIndex runIndex = 0;
for (; runIndex < runCount; runIndex++) {
    CTRunRef run = (CTRunRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(runArray, runIndex);
    CFIndex runGlyphCount = CTRunGetGlyphCount(run);
    Boolean drawSubstitutedGlyphsManually = false;
    CTFontRef runFont = CFDictionaryGetValue(CTRunGetAttributes(run), kCTFontAttributeName);

        // Determine if we need to draw substituted glyphs manually. Do so if the runFont is not the same as the overall font.
    if (self.dimsSubstitutedGlyphs && ![self.font isEqual:(__bridge UIFont *)runFont]) {
        drawSubstitutedGlyphsManually = true;
    }

    CFIndex runGlyphIndex = 0;
    for (; runGlyphIndex < runGlyphCount; runGlyphIndex++) {
        CFRange glyphRange = CFRangeMake(runGlyphIndex, 1);
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, -(glyphArcInfo[runGlyphIndex + glyphOffset].angle));

            // Center this glyph by moving left by half its width.
        CGFloat glyphWidth = glyphArcInfo[runGlyphIndex + glyphOffset].width;
        CGFloat halfGlyphWidth = glyphWidth / 2.0;
        CGPoint positionForThisGlyph = CGPointMake(textPosition.x - halfGlyphWidth, textPosition.y);

            // Glyphs are positioned relative to the text position for the line, so offset text position leftwards by this glyph's width in preparation for the next glyph.
        textPosition.x -= glyphWidth;

        CGAffineTransform textMatrix = CTRunGetTextMatrix(run);
        textMatrix.tx = positionForThisGlyph.x;
        textMatrix.ty = positionForThisGlyph.y;
        CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, textMatrix);

        if (!drawSubstitutedGlyphsManually) {
            CTRunDraw(run, context, glyphRange);
        } 
        else {
                // We need to draw the glyphs manually in this case because we are effectively applying a graphics operation by setting the context fill color. Normally we would use kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, but this does not apply as we don't know the ranges for the colors in advance, and we wanted demonstrate how to manually draw.
            CGFontRef cgFont = CTFontCopyGraphicsFont(runFont, NULL);
            CGGlyph glyph;
            CGPoint position;

            CTRunGetGlyphs(run, glyphRange, &glyph);
            CTRunGetPositions(run, glyphRange, &position);

            CGContextSetFont(context, cgFont);
            CGContextSetFontSize(context, CTFontGetSize(runFont));
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5);
            CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions(context, &glyph, &position, 1);

            CFRelease(cgFont);
        }

            // Draw the glyph bounds 
        if ((self.showsGlyphBounds) != 0) {
            CGRect glyphBounds = CTRunGetImageBounds(run, context, glyphRange);

            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            CGContextStrokeRect(context, glyphBounds);
        }
            // Draw the bounding boxes defined by the line metrics
        if ((self.showsLineMetrics) != 0) {
            CGRect lineMetrics;
            CGFloat ascent, descent;

            CTRunGetTypographicBounds(run, glyphRange, &ascent, &descent, NULL);

                // The glyph is centered around the y-axis
            lineMetrics.origin.x = -halfGlyphWidth;
            lineMetrics.origin.y = positionForThisGlyph.y - descent;
            lineMetrics.size.width = glyphWidth; 
            lineMetrics.size.height = ascent + descent;

            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            CGContextStrokeRect(context, lineMetrics);
        }
    }

    glyphOffset += runGlyphCount;
}

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetAlpha(context,0.0);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);

free(glyphArcInfo);
CFRelease(line);
```

}

```
@synthesize font = _font;
@synthesize text = _string;
@synthesize radius = _radius;
@synthesize color = _color;
@synthesize arcSize = _arcSize;
@synthesize shiftH = _shiftH;
@synthesize shiftV = _shiftV;
@synthesize shadowColor = _shadowColor;
@synthesize xOffsetShadow = _xOffsetShadow;
@synthesize blurShadow = _blurShadow;
@synthesize yOffsetShadow = _yOffsetShadow;

@dynamic attributedString;

- (NSAttributedString *)attributedString {
    // Create an attributed string with the current font and string.
assert(self.font != nil);
assert(self.text != nil);

    // Create our attributes...

    // font
CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)self.font.fontName, self.font.pointSize, NULL);

    // color
CGColorRef colorRef = self.color.CGColor;

    // pack it into attributes dictionary

NSDictionary *attributesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                (__bridge id)fontRef, (id)kCTFontAttributeName,
                                colorRef, (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                nil];
assert(attributesDict != nil);


    // Create the attributed string
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text attributes:attributesDict];

return attrString;
```

}

```
@end
```

Comment: Show the crash log. You are not supposed to add the customView as a subview *and* and the layer, if you did this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should really ask about the problem, not about your attempt to fix the problem:

```
[self.view addSubview:customView];
[layer addSublayer:customView.layer];
//Causes crashes the minute the screen is touched
```

You don't need to add the subview and the layer, just add the subview. What you're doing is disconnecting something, or overcorrecting something and generating unwanted behaviour.

If you want to add layers to layers then work with layers and not views. Views own their layers and you shouldn't try to disconnect them or have a layer retained when its view will be deallocated.

So, ideally, create a `CALayer` subclass and move all of the code you currently have into its `drawInContext:` method. It looks like you can basically just copy and paste it as all your current code draws into a `CGContext` anyway.

Comment: You answer makes perfect sense. Thanks! But I don't know how I would go about converting my custom UIview to a CAlayer. I posted my custom view code above. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need layers at all?

Comment: Because I'm drawing layers on a video using videoComposition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:compositionParentLayer];

Comment: My current workaround is to convert the UIView to a UIImage and add it to the CALayer.

Comment: You can probably move most of your code directly to a layer, or layer draw delegate as its using the drawing context directly.

Comment: Thanks for your help Wain. I tried that, but it didn't work. I got an invalid context error.

Comment: which generally means you tried to force the drawing rather than asking the system to run the drawing

Comment: What's the best way to call the delegate method drawLayer: inContext in my mainViewController?

Comment: you don't, you set the view or layer as needing display and the system will do it at the appropriate time (and setup the context to draw to before it tells you to draw)

Comment: I apologize, but I'm confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117538/discussion-between-wain-and-user1752054).

Comment: Wain, thanks again for your help. Following your advice, I was able to get to work.